# Swift Functional Programming - "Optional Bind" vs. "Optional Map"

Tags: swift

I've been working through the [Functional Programming in Swift](http://www.objc.io/books/) book, and I don't really have a good way to understand the differences in a concept introduced in the Optionals chapter.

The pattern when working with optionals tends to be:

```
if let thing = optionalThing {
    return doThing(thing)
}
else {
    return nil
}
```

This idiom is handled succinctly with the standard library function `map`

```
map(optionalThing) { thing in doThing(thing) }
```

The book then continues on and introduces the concept of optional binding, which is where my ability to differentiate starts to break down.

The book guides us to define the `map` function:

```
func map<T, U>(optional: T?, f: T -> U) -> U?
{
    if let x = optional {
        return f(x)
    }
    else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

And also guides us to define an optional binding function. *Note: the book uses the operator `>>=`, but I've chosen to use a named function because it helps me see the similarities.*

```
func optionalBind<T, U>(optional: T?, f: T -> U?) -> U?
{
    if let x = optional {
        return f(x)
    }
    else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

The implementation for both of these methods looks identical to me. The only difference between the two is the function argument they take:

- `map` takes a function that transforms a T into a U
- `optionalBind` takes a function that transforms a T into an optional U

The result of "nesting" these function calls hurts my brain:

```
func addOptionalsBind(optionalX: Int?, optionalY: Int?) -> Int?
{
    return optionalBind(optionalX) { x in
        optionalBind(optionalY) { y in
            x + y
        }
    }
}

func addOptionalsMap(optionalX: Int?, optionalY: Int?) -> Int?
{
    return map(optionalX) { x in
        map(optionalY) { y in
            x + y
        }
    }
}
```

- The `addOptionalsBind` function does exactly what you'd expect it to do.
- The `addOptionalsMap` function fails to compile stating:

> 'Int??' is not convertible to 'Int?'
>   
>   I feel like I'm close to understand what's happening here (and optional integer is being wrapped again in an optional? But how? why? hu?), but I am also far enough away from understanding that I'm not entirely sure of a smart question to ask.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What's happening might be clearer with a more verbose implementation of `addOptionalsMap`. Let's start with the innermost call to `map`—instead of what you have there, let's use this instead:

```
let mappedInternal: Int? = map(optionalY) { (y: Int) -> Int in
    return x + y
}
```

The closure provided to `map` takes an `Int` and returns and `Int`, while the call to `map` itself returns an optional: `Int?`. No surprises there! Let's move one step out and see what happens:

```
let mappedExternal: ??? = map(optionalX) { (x: ???) -> ??? in
    let mappedInternal: Int? = map(optionalY) { (y: Int) -> Int in
        return x + y
    }
    return mappedInternal
}
```

Here we can see our `mappedInternal` value from above, but there are a few types left undefined. `map` has a signature of `(T?, T -> U) -> U?`, so we only need to figure out what `T` and `U` are in this case. We know the return value of the closure, `mappedInternal`, is an `Int?`, so `U` becomes `Int?` here. `T`, on the other hand, can stay a non-optional `Int`. Substituting, we get this:

```
let mappedExternal: Int?? = map(optionalX) { (x: Int) -> Int? in
    let mappedInternal: Int? = map(optionalY) { (y: Int) -> Int in
        return x + y
    }
    return mappedInternal
}
```

The closure is `T -> U`, which evaluates to `Int -> Int?`, and the whole `map` expression ends up mapping `Int?` to `Int??`. Not what you had in mind!

---

Contrast that with the version using `optionalBind`, fully type-specified:

```
let boundExternal: ??? = optionalBind(optionalX) { (x: ???) -> ??? in
    let boundInternal: Int? = optionalBind(optionalY) { (y: Int) -> Int? in
        return x + y
    }
    return boundInternal
}
```

Let's look at those `???` types for this version. For `optionalBind` we need `T -> U?` closure, and have an `Int?` return value in `boundInternal`. So both `T` and `U` in this case can simply be `Int`, and our implementation looks like this:

```
let boundExternal: Int? = optionalBind(optionalX) { (x: Int) -> Int? in
    let boundInternal: Int? = optionalBind(optionalY) { (y: Int) -> Int? in
        return x + y
    }
    return boundInternal
}
```

---

Your confusion may come from the way variables can be "lifted" as optionals. It's easy to see when working with a single layer:

```
func optionalOpposite(num: Int?) -> Int? {
    if let num = num {
        return -num
    }
    return nil
}
```

`optionalOpposite` can be called with either a variable of type `Int?`, like it explicitly expects, or a non-optional variable of type `Int`. In this second case, the non-optional variable is implicitly converted to an optional (i.e., lifted) during the call.

`map(x: T, f: T -> U) -> U?` is doing the lifting in its return value. Since `f` is declared as `T -> U`, it never returns an optional `U?`. Yet the return value of `map` as `U?` means that `f(x)` gets lifted to `U?` on return.

In your example, the inner closure returns `x + y`, an `Int` that is lifted to an `Int?`. That value is then lifted again to `Int??` resulting in the type mismatch, since you've declared `addOptionalsMap` to return an `Int?`.

Answer (score 15):

> - map takes a function that transforms a T into a U
> - optionalBind takes a function that transforms a T into an optional U

Exactly. That is the entire difference. Let's consider a really simple function, `lift()`. It's going to convert `T` into `T?`. (In Haskell, that function would be called `return`, but that's a bit too confusing for non-Haskell programmers, and besides, `return` is a keyword).

```
func lift<T>(x: T) -> T? {
    return x
}

println([1].map(lift)) // [Optional(1)]
```

Great. Now what if we do that again:

```
println([1].map(lift).map(lift)) // [Optional(Optional(1))]
```

Hmmm. So now we have an `Int??`, and that's a pain to deal with. We'd really rather just have one level of optionalness. Let's build a function to do that. We'll call it `flatten` and flatten-down a double-optional to a single-optional.

```
func flatten<T>(x: T??) -> T? {
    switch x {
    case .Some(let x): return x
    case .None : return nil
    }
}

println([1].map(lift).map(lift).map(flatten)) // [Optional(1)]
```

Awesome. Just what we wanted. You know, that `.map(flatten)` happens a lot, so let's give it a name: `flatMap` (which is what languages like Scala call it). A couple of minutes of playing should prove to you that the implementation of `flatMap()` is exactly the implementation of `bindOptional` and they do the same thing. Take an optional and something that returns an optional, and get just a single level of "optional-ness" out of it.

This is a *really* common problem. It's so common that Haskell has a built-in operator for it (`>>=`). It's so common that Swift *also* has a built-in operator for it *if you use methods rather than functions*. It's called optional-chaining (it's a real shame that Swift doesn't extend this to functions, but Swift loves methods a lot more than it loves functions):

```
struct Name {
    let first: String? = nil
    let last: String? = nil
}

struct Person {
    let name: Name? = nil
}

let p:Person? = Person(name: Name(first: "Bob", last: "Jones"))
println(p?.name?.first) // Optional("Bob"), not Optional(Optional(Optional("Bob")))
```

`?.` is really just `flatMap` (*) which is really just `bindOptional`. Why the different names? Well, it turns out that "map and then flatten" is equivalent to another idea called the monadic bind which thinks about this problem a different way. Yep, monads and all that. If you think of `T?` as a monad (which it is), then `flatMap` turns out to be the bind operation that is required. (So "bind" is a more general term that applies to all monads, while "flat map" refers to the implementation detail. I find "flat map" easier to teach people first, but YMMV.)

If you want an even longer version of this discussion and how it can apply to other types than `Optional`, see [Flattenin' Your Mappenin'](http://robnapier.net/flatmap).

(*) `.?` can also sort of be `map` depending on what you pass. If you pass `T->U?` then it's `flatMap`. If you pass `T->U` then you can either think of it as being `map`, or you still think of it being `flatMap` where the `U` is implicitly promoted to `U?` (which Swift will do automatically).